# Merge wp-query and get_users

Tags: wp-query, users

Is there a way of merging `get_users()` and `and WP_Query()` into one query so I can paginate the results? I have two entities; users and companies. Both can be members but users are users and company is a custom post. I would like to merge the query together so I can control them at once i.e. pagination.

```
$args = array(
  'role'    => 'member',
  'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
  'order'   => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'category',
      'value'   => $category->term_id,
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
  ),
);

$users = get_users( $args );

$params = [
  'post_type' => 'member_company',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1,
  'member_category' => $category->slug,
  'posts_per_page' => 5
];

$query = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: Very unlikely, but if it was possible, I doubt it would be faster, some things just take multiple steps to do, muddying them by merging them isn't always an improvement

Comment: Performance wasn't really my worry to be honest.

Comment: Re-reading your question I see your actual issue is how to implement pagination, and that merging the two queries is simply a proposed solution. Which are you trying to paginate? Or are you trying to list both users and posts in the same archive? If so, I don't think that's feasible. Perhaps you can create a CPT automatically via hooks that you can query for

Comment: Well it's not just pagination but listing them together. It's quite confusing as there is a 3 way relation. There are categories (custom taxonomy). A user and a CPT can be within that category. Unfortunately, my old colleague did not create members as a CPT but just built it on top of default WP users. So I need a way of displaying both on the same page and paginate them. Both have their own template part as well.

Comment: You can't have both users and posts in the same custom taxonomy, WP has no way to know if you meant the post with ID 5 or the user with ID 5. Otherwise no, you can't merge the queries together like this